# Weighted average for Proc Tabulate

Tags: sas

I would like to see the weighted average in a proc tabulate. How would I go about this?

```
proc tabulate data=Result;
var ltv_max_onoff;
class Exposure_class_std_method;
table Exposure_class_std_method, ltv_max_onoff*mean;
run;
```

I figure I need to specify something else after the "ltv_max_onoff". Also I would need to specify what variable I would like to weight it on. A similar code that does work is the Proc Summary:

```
proc summary data=Result nway;
        var ltv_max_onoff;
        weight exp_distr_onoff;
        output out=WALTV (drop=_:)  mean= ;
run;
```

I would like this operation to be done in each category of the Proc Tabulate (Exposure_class_std_method).

I have tried putting the weight command in the "var" statement

```
proc tabulate data=Result;
var ltv_max_onoff weight=exp_distr_onoff;
class Exposure_class_std_method;
table Exposure_class_std_method, ltv_max_onoff;
run;
```

It's not recognised:

[image]

Comment: Look at both the WEIGHT and FREQ statement within PROC TABULATE.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WEIGHT statement or the WEIGHT= option on the VAR statement.

Comment: I tried this "var ltv_max_onoff weight=exp_distr_onoff;" But got the error "variable WEIGHT not found"

Comment: Did you happen to look at the documentation for the VAR statement?  You need to include a / before weight option.  SAS is even telling you in the ERROR 22-322.